# Radio button checking

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have four radio button in a row.
Name and id is same of all four button in a row.
Suppose, name and id for all buttons in first row is radiobutton0, for second row it is radiobutton1, for third row it is radiobutton2. Thus I have 10 rows in a table.
My aim is when I submit the page, one button must be checked in a row else it show a msg box that please fill the corresponding radio button.
I want to get the value of radio button either true or false.

I run the following code:

```
function get_radio_value()  
 {  
var  radioID="radiobutton";  
var radiobuttonName;  
var radiobuttonValue;  
for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {  
radiobuttonName=radioID+i;  
alert("radiobutton Name is:"+:"+radiobuttonName);  
}  
}
```

This method execute the loop and display all radiobutton names.
How I find `radiobuttonValue` which is either true or false.

Comment: Duplicate. I saw the exact same question yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

```
radiobuttonValue = document.getElementById(radiobuttonName).checked?true:false;
```

Answer (score 0):

radioObj =  Your Radio Button Object Id

```
var radioLength = radioObj.length;


for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {      if(radioObj[i].checked) {           alert("Radio Button Checked" + radioObj[i].value);      }else{
                  alert("Radio Button Not Checked" + radioObj[i].value);
                }   }
```